# Returning an unsigned integer array from a function in solidity?

Tags: javascript, c++, solidity

Which is the correct function definition for returning an unsigned integer array from a function in solidity?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

An array is defined with `[]` sign after the datatype, for example `uint256[]`.

Since array is a reference type, you also need to specify its [data location](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/types.html#data-location). In this case, the value is loaded from storage to memory, and then returned from `memory`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    uint256[] numbers;

    constructor() {
        numbers.push(123);
        numbers.push(456);
    }

    function getNumbers() public view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        return numbers;
    }
}
```